# run spring boot application in spring mvc application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I try to run spring boot app inside spring mvc
by adding spring boot app dependency in spring mvc pom
and scan spring boot package
but i faced below issue

```
    ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name anonymousFavouriteController: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field batchFileUploadService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name batchFileUploadServiceImpl: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field uploadedFilesRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [.bup.repository.UploadedFilesRepo]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: can you please paste the pom and the complete stack trace.

Comment: @joemokenela error updated

Comment: <springVersion>4.3.3.RELEASE</springVersion>

Comment: I don't understand, how it is possible to run spring boot app INSIDE spring mvc. If the question is about running multiple Spring context inside a single web application, we need much more information, than an error message.

Comment: I have spring mvc app and spring boot app , i need to use spring boot app inside spring mvc app, i added spring boot app dependency in spring mvc app and i used it but when i use service layer(spring boot app) in spring mcv i faced above error @30thh

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple Spring contexts inside a single application. It is generally a legal configuration, but in case of sophisticated applications (and MVC applications a always sophisticated) it will be definitely not easy to make both running.

I see at least two problems:

**Component scan** Both applications will scan packages and find classes belong to the application. You must check the list of packages don't overlap.

**DispatcherServlet** Every application will try to register it's own dispatcher servlet. You need to map every servlet only to selected paths which don't overlap either.

---

Spring MVC  and Spring Boot can be configured over plenty of different ways. It can be done over `web.xml`, annotations, Spring XML descriptors and wildest combinations of all these methods. I would start configuring with `web.xml`. Something like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>app1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-config-app1.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>app2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-config-app2.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>app1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app1/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- All other urls go to "app2" -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>app2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Both specified XML descriptor must define the packages to scan for every of two applications.